# Can I use R to only analyze data past a certain date?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, split

I have an excel sheet that I imported into RStudio which contains data for every subject of a certain population. Each subject has their own set of data with corresponding dates, but I only want to look at the data and perform statistical analyses on the dates past a unique date for each subject.

I'm assuming I can use the split function to create smaller dataframes, with each corresponding to that of each subject, and then use some function to analyze the data in a loop to run on all of the smaller dataframes I created from the split.

Some of these subjects with have over 1000 data points. My two main questions are:

1) Is there a function I can use to analyze the data for each subject past a specific unique date to each subject?

2) Is the strategy I proposed above a viable one?

I unfortunately have very little experience in data analyses or extensive any background in computer science. Thanks for any help.

Edit: So there was a request about the type of data I was talking about. I was wondering if I had data similar to this, could I still use the above strategy. Where P1 and P2 have their own data sets that I want to analyze after the TxDate.

```
>data
1           Date     BMI    Glucose    Cholesterol    TxDate    
2 P1                                                  3/3/15
3           12/1/14  24     145        99  
4           3/18/15  26     123        101          
5           4/21/15  28     111        85      
6           6/2/15   25     133        90         
7          
8
9 P2                                                  4/6/16
10          1/3/16   33     145        200
11          3/30/16  31     162        178
12          5/13/16  34     190        134
13          6/12/16  34     183        168
14          7/9/16   35     200        189
15          9/10/16  31     175        190
16          11/23/17 27     121        120
17
18
```

Comment: The task is trivial to implement in R when you have learned the basics of manipulating data.frames.

Comment: We could provide more specific guidance on how to begin if we knew more about your data's structure and the types of analyses you are seeking to implement. Could you provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions to get you started:

1) [Tidy](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) your data. To do this you could look into ways to modify your input data so it looks more like this:

```
  ID     Date     BMI    Glucose    Cholesterol  TxDate    
3 P1     12/1/14  24     145        99           3/3/15
4 P1     3/18/15  26     123        101          3/3/15      
5 P1     4/21/15  28     111        85           3/3/15 
6 P1     6/2/15   25     133        90           3/3/15     
10 P2    1/3/16   33     145        200          4/6/16
11 P2    3/30/16  31     162        178          4/6/16
12 P2    5/13/16  34     190        134          4/6/16
13 P2    6/12/16  34     183        168          4/6/16
14 P2    7/9/16   35     200        189          4/6/16
15 P2    9/10/16  31     175        190          4/6/16
16 P2    11/23/17 27     121        120          4/6/16
```

Notice the ID and TxDate column are filled in with the appropriate value and several rows were dropped. And row for ID, Date, etc. are actually 'headers', and not a data row. Don't  be too surprised if the tidying step takes longer than the analysis.

Now, for the purpose of this example lets use this as your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep("P1",4), rep("P2", 7)),
  Date = as.Date(mdy(c("12/1/14", "3/18/15", "4/21/15" , "6/2/15", "1/3/16", "3/30/16", "5/13/16", "6/12/16", "7/9/16", "9/10/16", "11/23/17"))),
  BMI = c(24,26,28,25,33,31,34,34,35,31,27),
  Glucose = c(145,123,111,133,145,12,190,183,200,175,121),
  Cholesterol = c(99,101,85,90,200,178,134,168,189,190,120),
  TxDate = as.Date(mdy(c("3/3/15", "3/3/15","3/3/15","3/3/15","4/6/16", "4/6/16","4/6/16","4/6/16","4/6/16","4/6/16","4/6/16"))),
  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

2) Check to see if your Date and TxDate columns are being represented as a `date` object.  If your data.frame is named 'df' then something like `is.date(df$Date)` and `is.date(df$TxDate)` will tell you. Or `str(df)`.

If not, read about ways to convert them to `date` objects, perhaps with the `as.Date()` function combined with `mdy()` from the `lubridate` package.

3) Once you have the dates represented as `date` objects you could `subset` the data frame with a simple logical statement, like this

```
# subset dataframe
df1 <- df[df$Date > df$TxDate, ]
```

Now `df1` should look like this:

```
   ID Date        BMI    Glucose    Cholesterol     TxDate
2  P1 2015-03-18  26     123         101            2015-03-03
3  P1 2015-04-21  28     111          85            2015-03-03
4  P1 2015-06-02  25     133          90            2015-03-03
7  P2 2016-05-13  34     190         134            2016-04-06
8  P2 2016-06-12  34     183         168            2016-04-06
9  P2 2016-07-09  35     200         189            2016-04-06
10 P2 2016-09-10  31     175         190            2016-04-06
11 P2 2017-11-23  27     121         120            2016-04-06
```

What's left is the data you seem to need for your analysis.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'll give this a whirl, but from my rudimentary knowledge, this looks like it's absolutely the solution.